# Non-public API usage: The app references non-public symbols: __XCTFailureFormat, __XCTFailureHandler

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store

I am using react-native to build iOS app. I have successfully uploaded the app to app store but itunes sent me this email, saying that there are some issues in my app so I can not upload this build.
[image: The email]

I have searched for the symbols in my whole react-native project. There are no results were found that match the __XCTFailureFormat or __XCTFailureHandler. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is an issue with React. `__XCTFailureFormat` and `__XCTFailureHandler` are part of XCTest, the unit testing framework.

My guess is that you have unit test files compiled and bundled in the target you use for AppStore release.

In the project view in Xcode, select the target used to release on the App Store, then go into the Build Phases tab and search for files that should be in the `Compile Source` section.

[image: List of compiled files]

Usually, unit tests filenames end with `Test` so it's easy to use the search filed to filter the list. Then, just remove these files and re-upload a new binary to the App Store.